# GAS Function not setting value as intended in sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the Google Sheet, it can be copied: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ffIRGiGkiy5WFzSAvWNOY_3cqNXgTAOtO6o8vxS-BFU/edit?usp=sharing

The Function 'AddNewMembers' does not function, even if "isAdded == "No" it will not setValue(recruit_id)

```js
function AddNewMembers(event){
  event = {range: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange()}
  CheckHandleSteamIDNotation(event)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var recruitment_log = ss.getSheetByName('RL1');
  var main_roster = ss.getSheetByName('Main Roster');
  var isAdded = recruitment_log.getRange('R3').getValue();
  if(isAdded == "No") {
    var recruit_id = "'" + recruitment_log.getRange('J3').getValue();
    main_roster.getRange('I100').setValue(recruit_id);
  }
}

function CheckHandleSteamIDNotation(event)
{
  let formSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let header = formSheet.getRange(1,1,1,formSheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  let formRange = formSheet.getRange(formSheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, formSheet.getMaxColumns());
  let formValues = formRange.getValues();
  for(let i = 0; i < header[0].length; i++)
  {
    if(header[0][i].includes("SteamID"))
    {
      formValues[0][i] = "'" + formValues[0][i];
    }
  }
  formRange.setValues(formValues);
}
```

Comment: What trigger are you using?

Comment: I've tried:
On Form Submit, Manually, On Spreadsheet Open, Every 1 Minute.

Comment: Are you using the onFormSubmit for a spreadsheet or for a form?

Comment: This is regarding the spreadsheet itself, it has nothing to do with the form.

Comment: Yes but there are two different onFormSubmit triggers and if you picked the wrong one that could explain the problem because you may not be getting a trigger.  So which one did you pick

Comment: Just curious how did you get spacer columns in the forms linked sheet?  Do you have blank questions?

Comment: check the conditions on your if-else statement.`recruitment_log.getRange('R3').getValue();` contains a YES value, that is why the if else is not meeting the conditions set

Comment: What is the use case for this script? would you want to get all No values on the "Added" column and add it to the main roster sheet?

Comment: It checks if "Is Added" = No, if it is No it's supposed to add the value to the Main Roster Sheet, a function then changes the "No" value to Yes.

Comment: So are you sure that you are using the correct trigger?

Comment: The trigger is definately correct.

Comment: You want to give us public access to a live spreadsheet?

Comment: How did you put spacer columns in the linked sheet?

Comment: If you copy the sheet it should have all the relevant code attached, I can't give complete edit access via a link right now.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the provided script above contains `var isAdded = recruitment_log.getRange('R3').getValue();` the value of `R3` is currently set to "Yes" that is why the condition for the script below is not running.

```
if(isAdded == "No") {
    var recruit_id = "'" + recruitment_log.getRange('J3').getValue();
    main_roster.getRange('I100').setValue(recruit_id);
  }
```

**Try this modification:**

```
function AddNewMembers(event) {
  event = { range: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange() }
  CheckHandleSteamIDNotation(event)
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var recruitment_log = ss.getSheetByName('RL1');
  var main_roster = ss.getSheetByName('Main Roster');
  
  //Gets all the data values on recruitment_log
  var isAdded = recruitment_log.getRange(3, 1, recruitment_log.getLastRow(), recruitment_log.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  //Gets the last row starting I17
  var lastrow = main_roster.getRange(17, 9, main_roster.getLastRow() , 1).getValues().filter((x => x > 1)).length
  //Sets the value on the last blank row
  isAdded.map(x => x[17].toString().toLocaleLowerCase() == "no" ? "'" + main_roster.getRange(17 + lastrow,9).setValue(x[9]) : x)

}
```

I made modifications on your `isAdded` variable to the following to get the entire range of data on RL1 sheet.

```
var isAdded = recruitment_log.getRange(3, 1, recruitment_log.getLastRow(), recruitment_log.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

This part of script was only used to get the current length of data for the New Operatives. Using `.filter()` method to filter out empty array elements, since `getValues()` gets blank cells if there is formatting applied on the spreadsheet.

```
var lastrow = main_roster.getRange(17, 9, main_roster.getLastRow() , 1).getValues().filter((x => x > 1)).length
```

Using ES6 `.map()` method to create a new array for the data that hasn't been added to the main roster sheet file.

```
isAdded.map(x => x[17].toString().toLocaleLowerCase() == "no" ? "'" + main_roster.getRange(17 + lastrow,9).setValue(x[9]) : x)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Reference:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#description

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for the feedback, will change the answer accordingly